# Find cause of multiple System.Web.Mvc references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, projects-and-solutions

Using dotPeek to examine the references of the main assembly of a web project, I see:

```
System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

The project references in Visual Studio only shows version 5.2.3.0. I've also searched the .csproj files of referenced projects.

Manage NuGet Packages only shows v5.2.3 of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.

Searching the `packages` folder only finds v5.2.30128.0 under `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45`.

`gacutil /l System.Web.Mvc` shows versions 3.0.0.0 and 4.0.0.0.

I've looked through the other references with dotPeek's References Hierarchy and I didn't find the old version.

*Per a reply I checked the Web.config; this was already present:*

```xml
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

*I also checked other Web.configs for conflicting versions.*

*In addition I tried setting Specific Version to True in the System.Web.Mvc reference properties. This made no difference.*

Are the multiple versions expected? If not, how can I find and remove the source of the old version?

Comment: is there any reference to it in your web.config in the assembly bindings section? if not you may want to add that.  It is more than likely a secondary dependency that is pulling it in.

Comment: Is it actually causing an issue?  If it is being referenced by one of your other components you could attempt to update all others.  But if it is not causing any errors I would just ignore it.

Comment: @Brian we experienced major latency issues under load and had to roll this update back. We're investigating every possible cause.

Comment: Try deleting the `output (bin)` and the `lib` folder of your project and re-reference the associated libraries. It solved me a similar issue because the **same dll** was present twice with different names in the output folder. Not sure if this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this to your web.config

```xml
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This basically test your application that for any version (from 1-5.2.3) of System.Web.MVC that is referenced in the application to use 5.2.3.0 instead.  more than likely you have a reference that still is looking for the specific version of 5.0.  This burns me all the time with JSON.net.

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion; I checked, and a similar redirect was already present (just going from version 0).

Comment: hmm and that is interesting.  Perhaps try setting the System.Web.MVC reference flag "Use Specific Version" to true? I feel your pain on this one.

Comment: Another place to check is the web.config in the Views folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove multiple existing `dependency` from reference. After that add `reference` that you want to keep in your project.

And from property window you can see the version on current `dependency`. Check that version from that and set version in `web.config` file.

Comment: -1. As I explicitly stated, the project references in Visual Studio only shows version 5.2.3.0. I also stated that the version is set in the Web.config.